# What could make GetCursorPos return incorrect coordinates of {0,0}?

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi

We are seeing bad behavior in an application when it runs on Server 2008 (not R2).  This is a WinForms application, and Control.MousePosition is returning {0,0} no matter where the mouse is on the screen...  Control.MousePosition just makes a P/Invoke call to Win32 api GetCursorPos().

Followup:

I am using Control.MousePosition from WinForms, which calls GetCursorPos, and I can see that it definitely ignores the return value.  Asking my question another way, "What can cause GetCursorPos() to suddenly start returning FALSE, when it worked only milliseconds before in the same process?"

```
// From .NET Reflector....
public static Point get_MousePosition()
{
    NativeMethods.POINT pt = new NativeMethods.POINT();
    UnsafeNativeMethods.GetCursorPos(pt);
    return new Point(pt.x, pt.y);
}
```

There is a control in our library that calls SetWindowsHookEx to hook WH_CALLWNDPROCRET for our entire process.  I'm suspicious of this code, but tracing statements show that we're getting in + out of that hook cleanly.

What else should I be looking for?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Are you checking the return value of GetCursorPos, is it possibly failing? And can you share the P/Invoke declaration, maybe there is something wrong there.

Comment: Call `GetLastError()` if `GetCursorPos()` returns `false` and see what the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this can happen with /LARGEADDRESSAWARE 32 bit applications running on 64 bit Server 2008 R1 only.

Comment: Can you cite your source for this answer? Did Microsoft tell you this or do you remember how you figured it out? Is there some solution? I use GetCursorPos() a lot and I'd like to avoid any potential issue like that. Thanks

Comment: I work on Windows10 and just had that problem. I have no explanation why, but storing the boolean returned value into some variable just solved the problem. In the past I'd call it like a void function (and that worked until some while ago).

Answer (score 1):

To find out what the problem is you should add some error checking. If `GetCursorPos` returns `false`, call `GetLastError`, then throw the resulting value as an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what could be doing that, but i've never called that function.  I always just assumed it returned the position only if it was in the control, but it looks like I was wrong.

Have you tried Cursor.Position?  ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.position.aspx))

** I should add that this method uses the same code, basically, internally, but it might just be worth trying.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current.Position

//returns this for me:
{X = 1941 Y = 535}
    Empty: {X = 0 Y = 0}
    IsEmpty: False
    X: 1941
    Y: 535
```